# MongoDB, how to update all the docs in a collection, adding a new attribute randomly?

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to update all the docs in a collection adding a new attribute with values random between true and false.

I am running this query

```
try {
   db.COLLECTION.updateMany(
      {},
      { $set: { "ATTRIBUTE" : [true,false][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] } }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

However, I am getting all the docs updated with the same value. What is the problem?

Version Mongo 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: The general idea is to iterate all the documents in the collection and update each doc within the loop to get a unique random attribute.

Comment: It won't work the way you want, because `[true,false][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] ` will only be calculated once and will be updated with same value in all the records.

Comment: Exactly, I thought it was going to recalculate all the time...Too many hours in front of my pc :) Thx +1